# Is there a way to layout Swing components like divs in HTML?

Tags: java, swing, layout, html

Let's imagine situation where you're making the layout for a webpage. In HTML you can put the stuff in divs and use CSS to set positioning, e.g. size, positioning, etc.

Let's have another situatinon, but same requirements. You're programing in Java Swing, and you also want to make layout with similar requirements, e.g. size, positioning, etc.

I haven't found layout managers useful in this situation, because they make it one way, but never as you want it, e.g. one part will be next to another part, and it will have some size.

*In short:* I want the *layout* to handle *positioning* and *setting sizes* of GUI parts as happens with divs in HTML & CSS. I'm programing it in Java Swing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've tried [swinghtmltemplate](http://code.google.com/p/swinghtmltemplate/), but know about [xito](http://xito.sourceforge.net/projects/tablelayout/index.php) try to look through these projects, maybe you will find good solution for you. And yes, there is [MiG layout](http://www.miglayout.com/)

Comment: It's really interesting. I'll probably use the MIG layout :]

Comment: @user1097772 Its almost a year... if you have tried MIG layout or some other framework, can you please share your experience?

Comment: @dips I used MIG layout, you just need to download jar library from this page http://www.miglayout.com/ and add to your project. Than you should download manual with examples. It's really easy to use it. You can learn to use it in about 20 minutes. I can hightly recommed it to you. Also the code is better - its about half shorter than from shitty swing layouts. I have no problems with it, bud I used it only once on one school project (GUI for client of simple network boar game).

Comment: @user1097772 thanks! I have already started using it in a scala project, and it is working fine.

Comment: @dips You're welcome :) It's one of tools which made pepole with head on the neck.